# How to count the hours of a time-interval that fall in certain periods of time?

Tags: r

We share cars and the price depends on the period of time. So we have a "daylight-price" from 7:00 to 20:00 °clock and one "night-price" from 20:00 to 7:00 °clock. When somebody uses the car for some days i want to count the whole number of hours during the daylight- an night-times. So it is possible to calculate the price for the usage of the car.

I need to have two additional columns like "daylight" and "night". I am looking for a quick method to do this, because there are some hundredthousend shares.

input:

```
id; begin; end
1; 2019-06-03 14:00; 2019-06-06 03:30
```

expected output:

```
id; begin; end; daylight; night
1; 2019-06-03 14:00; 2019-06-06 03:30; 32; 29.5
```

Answer (score 1):

For dates starting and ending *exactly* at midnight, this is easy. A rough estimate is that there are 11 hours night time and 13 hours daylight per 24-hour day, so diff the two dates and multiply by respectively 11 and 13.

For the remaining records, we can deconstruct the edge-cases in two groups:

- If you start *earlier* than midnight, how many hours from start till midnight is nighttime and daylight time?
- If you end *later* than midnight, how many hours did you pass through from midnight?

As you might have guessed, we have 3 parts to the puzzle that simply needs to be added together: 1) from starting hour to midnight, 2) from midnight-after-start to midnight-before-start, and 3) from midnight-before-start to ending hour.

For 1) and 3), I've elected to split the nighttime hours into the hours in am and pm respectively.

Adding some more cases to check with, we can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df <- read.table(text='id; begin; end
1; 2019-06-03 14:00; 2019-06-06 03:30
2; 2019-06-03 22:00; 2019-06-06 14:00
3; 2019-06-03 02:00; 2019-06-06 22:30', sep=';', header=TRUE) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(begin, end), as.POSIXct)

df %>% mutate(
  begin_date = floor_date(begin, 'd'),
  hours_into_begin_day = hour(begin) + minute(begin)/60,
  begin_morning = pmax(0, pmin(7, 7-hours_into_begin_day)),
  begin_daylight = pmax(0,pmin(13, 20 - hours_into_begin_day)),
  begin_evening = pmin(24 - hours_into_begin_day , 4),

  hours_into_end_day = hour(end) + minute(end)/60,
  end_morning = pmin(7, hours_into_end_day),
  end_daylight = pmax(0, pmin(13, hours_into_end_day-7)),
  end_evening = pmax(0,hours_into_end_day-20),

  days_between = floor_date(end, 'd') - ceiling_date(begin, 'd'),
  daylight = as.integer(days_between) * 13 + begin_daylight + end_daylight,
  night = as.integer(days_between) * 11 + begin_morning + begin_evening + end_morning + end_evening
)


#  id               begin                 end begin_date hours_into_begin_day begin_morning begin_daylight begin_evening hours_into_end_day end_morning end_daylight end_evening days_between  daylight night 
#   1 2019-06-03 14:00:00 2019-06-06 03:30:00 2019-06-03                   14             0              6             4                3.5         3.5            0         0.0       2 days        32  29.5
#   2 2019-06-03 22:00:00 2019-06-06 14:00:00 2019-06-03                   22             0              0             2               14.0         7.0            7         0.0       2 days        33  31.0
#   3 2019-06-03 02:00:00 2019-06-06 22:30:00 2019-06-03                    2             5             13             4               22.5         7.0           13         2.5       2 days        52  40.5
```

Try fiddling with the `pmin` and `pmax` statements to see how they work. They are used in contrary to our intuition (IMHO), and are niftier than e.g. `begin_morning = ifelse(hours_into_begin_day < 7, hours_into_begin_day - 7, 0)`, which was my first approach.

Comment: The note to use floor_date(begin, 'd') and ceiling_date(begin, 'd') was very helpful, Thank you. I will try your code and think, it is ok.